# Delete previous month, before appending new data

Tags: python, database, scripting, spotfire

I'm setting up a new data table in SpotFire. Since the newest update SpotFire X, the Automation Service Job Builder is available for us. Therefore I want to create job schedule which will automatically append (new) data into my existing data table. I am pretty new with scripting and programming so any help would be so appreciated. I have a SAP BW Query which is connected with my Spotfire dashboards. This query only contains the latest month of data. Since the Automation Service Job Builder only have a weekly interval, I want to implement some intelligence before letting the scheduler adding data. The query will not refresh every week/day but every month. That's why I want the script to delete (if possible) the data first before appending the data to the data table, otherwise I will get duplicates in the data table.

I tried to search for scripts, but couldn't find anything usefull. I do have found this script.

```
dtTarget=usertable*
selection = IndexSet(dtTarget.RowCount,True)
for r in selection:
selection[r] = (r>=(dtTarget.RowCount-10))
dtTarget.RemoveRows(RowSelection(selection))
```

Comment: what's the actual problem you're having? does this code work? does it throw an error? where is the original source of the data (database, excel, data connection)? it's confusing because you say SAPBW is providing data, but then you are trying to delete it? generally speaking, Spotfire shouldn't be used to manipulate data in this way; that should be left to whatever service is providing said data.

Answer (score 1):

For my example code below, I've used a Spotfire file with the following:

Spotfire Datatable name = Store

Name of data column holding the date = [Date]

The data was loaded from the Spotfire demodata database.

If you just want to clear the table before loading, you can use this.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import RowSelection, IndexSet    
table = Document.Data.Tables["Store"]
table.RemoveRows(RowSelection(IndexSet(table.RowCount, True)))
```

If you want to delete everything older than last month, but keep everything newer, this will do it. Passing None into the last_month function will cause it to get last month as of today.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import RowSelection

def last_month(from_date):
    if from_date is None:
        from_date = date.today()
    end_date = from_date.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
    start_date = date(end_date.year, end_date.month, 1)
    return (start_date, end_date)

table = Document.Data.Tables["Store"]
(start,end) = last_month(date(1994,12,6))
rows_to_delete = table.Select("[Date] <= Date('{}')".format(end.strftime("%x")))
table.RemoveRows(rows_to_delete)
```

You can set the actual table as an input parameter to the ironpython script instead of naming it directly in the script as I've done. You can do the same with the date column name.